# How do I link a Facebook Page with a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

Is it better to store facebook link as

```
facebook = models.URLField (with the complete url)
```

or

```
facebook = models.CharField (with only the page name facebook.com/page/[this])
```

or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a `URLField`. Also make sure if a `URLField` is intended for a facebook url then you must check whether user input a facebook url or another url e.g. Google url (which is also a valid url)

You can also write custom validation method to further check if the link posted is active or not using [URLValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#urlvalidator)

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

validate = URLValidator(verify_exists=True)
validate(facebook_url)
```